# Android - Creating a on click listener to a Button and a extended ImageView on the same activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have these things, in a activity i set a onTouchListener to my ImageDraw, that extends the ImageView class, with this listener I perform actions like zoom and pan with gestures

But in this activity i have a button to, but when a set the onClickListener to the button i get i NullPointerException.

Without setting the onClickListener everything works fine.

My ImageDraw class is:

```
public class ImageDraw extends ImageView{
private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
List<Point> pts = new ArrayList<Point>() ;

public ImageDraw(Context context) {
    super(context);

}
//used to send the location of the points to draw on the screen
//must be called before every redraw to update the points on the screen
public void SetPointsToDraw(List<Point> pts)
{
    this.pts = pts;
}


public ImageDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context,attrs);
}
public ImageDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paintColor = mPaint;
    paintColor.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paintColor.setStrokeWidth(3);


    if(pts.size() > 0)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(pts.get(0).x, pts.get(0).y, 7, paintColor);   
    }
    if (pts.size() > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < pts.size(); i++) {
            paintColor.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            canvas.drawCircle(pts.get(i).x, pts.get(i).y, 7, paintColor);
            paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawLine(pts.get(i-1).x, pts.get(i-1).y, pts.get(i).x, pts.get(i).y, paintColor);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Edited:

Here is where i set the onClickListener to the button, and its here where te excpetion is throw. Exactly on the btnNew.SetOnTouchListener

```
        Button btnNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
    try
    {
    btnNew.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewWaypoint.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String teste = e.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the code that gives an error-'

Comment: If it is in a layout, looks like your layout may not be inflated. need more information as to where you r setting the onClickListener on the button

Comment: Do you know from where the NullPointerException is thrown?

Comment: I updated with the part of the code that throws the exception

Comment: I tried to put the xml too, but its is not being displayed

Comment: The @chaitanya comment helped me to think, i was trying to get the button from another layout that as not inflated, i consider the thread closed.... thanks all of you

Comment: @ fvz Can you post the full activity, the image view and the stack trace? My best guess right now is that you don't set the content view in the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess right now is that you don't set the content view in the activity. can you post your stack trace and activity code?

Answer (score 0):

I've meet the similar question, but I found that I forget to setcontentView in the activity. Hope it can help you.